# How to implement ListIterator?

Tags: java, arraylist, implementation, listiterator

I created this extension of ArrayList, NullIgnoringArrayList, because it's possible that my application will add nulls from time to time. I know there are various other ways to deal with this, like checking for null before inserting or filtering out nulls when accessing the ArrayList. But I got it in my head to do it this way and it was going fine but now I don't know how to proceed.

I should implement ListIterator because my tests call upon this method. I peaked in the implementation inside ArrayList but there ListItr is a private class that uses the private fields of ArrayList, which I don't have in NullIgnoringArrayList.

To be fair though, I might be overengineering and maybe I should just drop it. On the other hand, one might learn a thing or two.

NullIgnoringArrayList:

```
public class NullIgnoringArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(T element) {
        return !isNull(element) && super.add(element);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        if (isNull(element)) {
            return;
        }
        super.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection c) {
        return !isNull(c) && super.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection c) {
        return !isNull(c) && super.addAll(index, c);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator listIterator() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator listIterator(int index) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

SimpleListIterator:

```
public class SimpleListIterator<T> implements ListIterator {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object previous() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int nextIndex() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int previousIndex() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {

    }

    @Override
    public void set(Object o) {

    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object o) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with Java's ArrayList, but can't you just use the existing one, i.e. the one that ArrayList implements? Do you really have to implement your own, terribly dysfunctional one?

Comment: It might be better to extend [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **delegate** method calls to `ListIterator<T>` of the parent:

```
public class NullIgnoringArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    ...

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        return new SimpleListIterator<>(super.listIterator());
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
        return new SimpleListIterator<>(super.listIterator(index));
    }
}

public class SimpleListIterator<T> implements ListIterator<T> {

    private final ListIterator<T> underlying;

    public SimpleListIterator(ListIterator<T> underlying) {
        this.underlying = underlying;
    }

    @Override public boolean hasNext() {return underlying.hasNext();}
    @Override public T next() { return underlying.next(); }
    @Override public boolean hasPrevious() {return underlying.hasPrevious();}
    @Override public T previous() {return underlying.previous();}
    @Override public int nextIndex() {return underlying.nextIndex();}
    @Override public int previousIndex() {return underlying.previousIndex();}
    @Override public void remove() { underlying.remove();}

    @Override
    public void set(T o) {
        if (isNull(o)) {return;}
        underlying.set(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T o) {
        if (isNull(o)) {return;}
        underlying.add(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that ListIterator has its own add method that in this case also needed to be overridden to ignore null. This suggestion helped me accomplish this, ty